# Adding autofill/autocomplete suggestion to text input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, autocomplete, textfield

I have tried several ways to add autocomplete/autofill suggestion functionality on text input. I have set a list 'names' for which I want autofill suggestions when being searched.

I tried this code which I got from pypi.org (https://pypi.org/project/fast-autocomplete/). It has library named fast-autocomplete. I tried using it but the problem I am facing here is that it is not giving me real-time autocomplete suggestions.

```
from fast_autocomplete import AutoComplete
words = {'book': {}, 'burrito': {}, 'pizza': {}, 'pasta':{}}
autocomplete = AutoComplete(words=words)

autocomplete.search(input('Type the word \n'), max_cost=3, size=3)
```

The output coming, is that when I type in the input, it is not giving me realtime suggestions. Once I have entered the word, then it is displaying the suggestions. I want the suggestions to be displayed realtime based on list like just how Google works.

[image]

[image]

This is the second example for the same-
[image]

[image]

I have tried this. I want the suggestions to be displayed on the input text. Kindly help me.

Comment: `input()` send text to `search()` only when you click `Enter` - it would to modify code in `input()` and check text after every char. And it would need to add some widget to display it at the same time. So all this can be complex task.

Comment: see [Get all callbacks/handlers of a widget - Widgets - Jupyter Community Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/get-all-callbacks-handlers-of-a-widget/11702). It seems you can assign function to `input` and this function can use `autocomplete` - but still there is problem to display these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` sends text to `search()` only when you click `Enter` and I don't know if you can change it

But using `widget.Text` I could assign function which is executed always when there is new text in widget. To display result I use `widget.Label` but you could try to use `Combobox`

Doc: [Widget List — Jupyter Widgets 8.0.2 documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html)

```
import ipywidgets

from fast_autocomplete import AutoComplete

words = {'book': {}, 'burrito': {}, 'pizza': {}, 'pasta':{}}
autocomplete = AutoComplete(words=words)

def on_change(data):
    #print(data)
    
    text = data['new']
    #print(text)
    
    values = autocomplete.search(text, max_cost=3, size=3)
    #print(values)
    
    # convert nested list to string
    #values = ', '.join(sorted(set(str(item) for sublist in values for item in sublist)))

    values = str(values)
    #print(values)
    
    label.value = values
    
label = widgets.Label()

text = ipywidgets.Text(
    value='',
    placeholder='Type something',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)
text.observe(on_change, names='value')

display(text, label)
```

---

**BTW:**

on page with `jupyter-widgets` I found
[adding autocompletion for Text? · Issue #692 · jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/692)
but it seems they still didn't create it.

---

**EDIT:**

Version which uses `Combobox` instead of `Text`+`Label`.

It can more useful because you can select value from list - but I see it doesn't clear list in HTML so later it can display the same value few times. Some workaround is to clear it with `JavaScript` but it could be better to use `ID` instead of tag `datalist` but I didn't find `ID` in python code.

**EDIT:** I added `Button` and `on_click()` in code.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import Javascript, display

from fast_autocomplete import AutoComplete

words = {'book': {}, 'burrito': {}, 'pizza': {}, 'pasta':{}}
autocomplete = AutoComplete(words=words)

def on_change(data):
    global text  # inform function to use global `text` instead of local `text` when you assign `text = ...`
    
    #print(data)

    text = data['new']
    #print(text)

    values = autocomplete.search(text, max_cost=3, size=3)
    #print(values)
    
    # convert nested list to flat list
    values = list(sorted(set(str(item) for sublist in values for item in sublist)))
    #print(values)
        
    # remove previous options from tag `<datalist>` in HTML
    display(Javascript(""" document.querySelector("datalist").innerHTML = "" """))
    
    combo.options = values
    
combo = widgets.Combobox(
    value='',
    placeholder='Type something',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)
combo.observe(on_change, names='value')

def your_function(widget):
    print('widget:', widget)
    print('global text:', text)
    # here make all calculations
    
button = widgets.Button(description='OK')
button.on_click(your_function)

display(combo, button)
```

[image]

Comment: Once I have selected an option, I want to store the selected value in one variable which I can use lated. I want to select the value from the autocomplete/autofill dropdown and get it stored in a vrariable. How to do that?

Comment: you have to assign `data['new']` to `global` variable. I don't know if `Combobox` can execute function when you select data - so it may need `Button` to execute function

Comment: Can you tell me that how to connect the button to combobox widget? I have added the button functionality

Comment: button = widgets.Button(
    description='Click me',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    tooltip='Click me',
    icon='check' # (FontAwesome names without the `fa-` prefix)
)
button

I have added this code

Comment: let me know that how I should ass the button?

Comment: if you see my first link in answer then you should see example code in documentation. Button needs `button.on_click(your_function)` (without `()`) and in `def your_function(): ...` you should get value from `global` variable and use it in your calculations.

Comment: I added `Button` and `on_click` in code in answer.

Comment: if my answer helped you then you could mark my answer as accepted.